# My Jabber bot gets stuck -- how to throttle message sending?

Tags: python

I have my own jabber bot, and today I made a new plugin, which is to send message for all users. My code was working well, but I have a small problem; when I give my bot the command to send a message, my bot gets stuck and disconnects.

I know why my bot gets stuck and disconnects; I have more than 2000 users, so my bot cannot send a message at the same time for all users. Is there any method in Python to make my code send the message for each user after N seconds? I mean have the bot send MSG for user1, then wait for N seconds and send for user2, etc.

I hope my idea is clear. This is my code:

```
def send_msg(type, source, parameters):
    ADMINFILE = 'modules/xmpp/users.cfg'
    fp = open(ADMINFILE, 'r')
    users = eval(fp.read())
    if parameters:
        for z in users:
            msg(z, u"MSG from Admin:\n" +parameters)
            reply(type, source, u"MSG has been sent!")
        else:
            reply(type, source, u"Error! please try again.")


register_command_handler(send_msg, 'msg', ['all','amsg'], 0,'Sends a message to all users')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `time.sleep(secs)`. [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> Suspend execution for the given number of seconds. The argument may be
>   a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The
>   actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any
>   caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that
>   signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer
>   than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of
>   other activity in the system.

After each send you can delay for `time.sleep(seconds)` before sending your next message.

Comment: Hi, i know about time.sleep(x) but i dont need to sleep my programme after each MSG its not a problem. I need to send MSG for user1 then my programme sleep fo X second then send for user2 and like that.. I have more than 2000 users so my bot can't send one MSG for 2000 accounts in the same time. That's what i need.

Comment: Sounds like the same thing. If you put a time.sleep(x) after your send or reply, that's what it would do.

Comment: I try it and i get the same problem but when i send for 15 users its working as well but if the users more than 15 it get stuck.

Comment: Can't edit your code, that'd change your question. :) I would put the sleep after the `reply` in your `for` loop. That should send the message, post your reply, then wait whatever time you have specified. If you did that, are you sure this is your problem?

Comment: Yes i do like that. I put the sleep after reply & the bot get stuck again.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different problem. Perhaps not a long enough sleep?

Comment: I try to put different sleep but the same problem i face. What's more, when i put < 15 users in ADMINFILE it's working as well but if it's more than 15 users the bot get stuck.